# HTML pair tag highlight alternative for Geany editor on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, geany

Is there any plugin or other option to achieve this functionality. What I want is if I select an opening tag or place cursor near to it its matching closing tag should be highlighted either through a straight line or changing colour of both the opening and closing tags.

I search the net for it and found out that one such plugin existed called [pairtaghighlighter](http://plugins.geany.org/pairtaghighlighter.html) but it is not supported now.

So I ask for some other plugin which achieves same functionality.

Comment: I installed all the plugins via `sudo apt-get install geany-plugins` then open `geany` and went to the `plugin manager` and checked it. Then it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install the [pairtaghighlighter](https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins/tree/master/pairtaghighlighter) plugin from the geany-plugins master branch. Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins.git
cd geany-plugins/
sed -i 's/1.24/1.23/' wscript
./waf configure --enable-plugins=pairtaghighlighter
make all
sudo make install
```

Restart Geany and enable the plugin in Tools -> Plugin Manager:

[image]

Now you can easily highlight the two tags:

[image]

Comment: This was helpful answer. At first it didn't install successfully. Then I copy pasted commands and it did. Thanks a ton.

Comment: It's not working for me. It complains after running `sed -i 's/1.24/1.23/' wscript` with the following error message `sed: can't read wscript: No such file or directory`

Comment: @PhemeloKhetho it's an old answer. If you're running 20.04, just install the plugin with `sudo apt install geany-plugin-pairtaghighlighter`

Comment: @SylvainPineau got it. Thanks!