# A alternative to install pairtaghighlighter for geany 1.23.21

Tags: plugins, geany

I prove to install this plugin following the instructions of this post: [HTML pair tag highlight alternative for Geany editor on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589172/html-pair-tag-highlight-alternative-for-geany-editor-on-ubuntu-14-04)

but, when I write

```
sed -i 's/1.24/1.23/' wscript
```

it says me this:

```
fatal: destination path 'geany-plugins' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

What can I do?

after

```
./waf configure --enable-plugins=pairtaghighlighter
```

it appears me this:

```
Setting top to                           : /tmp/geany-plugins 
Setting out to                           : /tmp/geany-plugins/_build_ 
Checking for waf version in 1.6.1-1.7.0  : ok 
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program pkg-config          : /usr/bin/pkg-config 
Checking for 'gtk+-2.0' >= 2.16.0        : not found 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /tmp/geany-plugins/_build_/config.log)
```

Comment: The enumerated steps work perfectly.

Comment: for me no, thath's why i ask.

Comment: List all steps that you're gone. Somewhere is a mistake.

Comment: but where can be?¿

Comment: If i put and image of the terminal,  can be useful ?¿

Comment: Can be, let's see.

Comment: But my Ubuntu is not in English... You will not understand the terminal

Comment: That you can switch temporarily. `LANG=C`

Comment: how can I send the photo to you ?¿

Comment: Not necessary. Problem solved, see my answer

Comment: How many times have you run `git clone ...`?

Comment: a lot, so what I have to do?¿

Comment: but now appears me to:" The configuration failed
(complete log in /tmp/geany-plugins/_build_/config.log)"                                                              After I put "
./waf configure --enable-plugins=pairtaghighlighter"

Comment: I can't read the log =)

Comment: So what I have to do ?¿

Comment: Post the error message in your question.

Comment: Everything after `./waf configure ...`

Comment: Answered: `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This has nothing to do with the `sed -i 's/1.24/1.23/' wscript`.

   This is an error message from Git. You start the command `git clone https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins.git` several times. Then Git complains.

   *Example:*

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins.git

   Cloning into 'geany-plugins'...
   remote: Counting objects: 15302, done.
   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
   remote: Total 15302 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 15287
   Receiving objects: 100% (15302/15302), 14.59 MiB | 1.17 MiB/s, done.
   Resolving deltas: 100% (8708/8708), done.
   Checking connectivity... done.

   $ git clone https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins.git

   fatal: destination path 'geany-plugins' already exists and is not an empty directory.
   ```
2. Install the gtk2 development library:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
   ```

   and again:

   ```
   ./waf configure --enable-plugins=pairtaghighlighter
   ```

Comment: Wait, so I have to write "sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev" and then...

Comment: `./waf configure --enable-plugins=pairtaghighlighter`

Comment: It says me :   "bash: ./waf: The folder doesn’t exist"

Comment: Grmpf `cd /tmp/geany-plugins/` and `./waf configure --enable-plugins=pairtaghighlighter`

Comment: I have a problem yet, when I write `./waf configure --enable-plugins=pairtaghighlighter` it says me this `Could not find 'intltool-merge'
(complete log in /tmp/geany-plugins/_build_/config.log)
`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install intltool`

Comment: Thanks bro, you are the best, thanks you for all the time you spend hire helping me. If I can do something for you only say it :) Danke!!!